# Filter with jQuery by input range

Tags: jquery, html

A few days ago, I asked on this forum about filter with jQuery. Some people helped me but now I need to do filter no by checkboxes, but with input type="range". 
Is it possible? 
My code looks like:
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ajwj7kt9/3/)

My code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input.szukajnapraw').on('click', function () {
        var $checked = $('input.szukajnapraw:checked'),
            $trs = $('.results > tr');
        $trs.toggle(!$checked.length);
        if ($checked.length) {
            $checked.each(function () {
                var text = $(this).attr('rel').trim().toLowerCase();
                $trs.find('td:nth-child(1),td:nth-child(4),td:nth-child(7),td:nth-child(13)').filter(function(){
                    return text == $(this).text().trim().toLowerCase();
                }).parent().show();
            })
        }
    }).last().change();
});
```

```html
<div class="box col-md-10 items">
            <label>Ilość dysków</label>
            <input type="range" min="1" max="24" />
            </div>
            <div class="box col-md-10 items">
            <label>Pojemność</label>
            <input type="range" id="range1" min="1" max="96" />
            </div>
            <div class="box col-md-10 items">
            <label>Wydajność</label>
            <input type="range" min="50" max="2000" />
  </div>


<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Producent</th>
                <th>Produkt</th>
                <th>Foto</th>
                <th>Typ</th>
                <th>Cena netto</th>
                <th>Cena brutto</th>
                <th>Interface</th>
                <th>Ilość dysków</th>
                <th>Pojemność</th>
                <th>RAID</th>
                <th>Wydajność</th>
                <th>Opis</th>
                <th>Specyfikacja</th>
                <th>Zakup</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
 
            <tbody class="results">
            <tr> <td>Tiger Technology</td><td>Macierz 123 TEST</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/ff.jpg" style = "width:50px;height:50px;"/></td><td>NAS Network Attached Storage</td><td>69.00</td><td>124.00</td><td>Thunderbolt2</td><td>60</td><td>5tb</td><td>0 1</td><td>Duża</td><td>dsadsadasdawderwasfcagfae</td><td style='display:none;'>1</td><td><a href=http://www.google.pl target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='30' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr><tr> <td>G-Tech</td><td>vcxv</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/" style = "width:50px;height:50px;"/></td><td>DAS Direct Attached Storage</td><td>50.00</td><td>70.00</td><td>USB 3.0</td><td>5</td><td>400</td><td>5*5*</td><td>500</td><td>dsadsad</td><td style='display:none;'>1</td><td><a href=http://www.o2.pl target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='34' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr><tr> <td>Tiger Technology</td><td>das sad</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/IMG_20150504_074450.jpg" style = "width:50px;height:50px;"/></td><td>SAN Srorage Area Network</td><td>50.00</td><td>70.00</td><td>eSATA</td><td>6</td><td>400</td><td>5/8/8</td><td>500</td><td>dasdasdsa</td><td style='display:none;'>2</td><td><a href=http://www.nw.pl target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='35' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr><tr> <td>LaCie</td><td>Macierz</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/depositphotos_12071772-Website-Development-PHP-HTML-Arrows.jpg" style = "width:50px;height:50px;"/></td><td>SAN Srorage Area Network</td><td>98.00</td><td>120.00</td><td>miniSAS</td><td>6</td><td>4 TB</td><td>5</td><td>Duża</td><td>Tu powinien być opis, ale testuje i go nie wpisuje! </td><td style='display:none;'>2</td><td><a href=http://www.google.pl target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='36' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr><tr> <td>LaCie</td><td>dsad</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/IMG_20150504_074450.jpg" style = "width:50px;height:50px;"/></td><td>SAN Srorage Area Network</td><td>50.00</td><td>70.00</td><td>Thunderbolt</td><td>8</td><td>400</td><td>8/8/8</td><td>500</td><td>fasdf</td><td style='display:none;'>2</td><td><a href=http://fsdfsdf target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='37' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr><tr> <td>mLogic</td><td>test</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/ff.jpg" style = "width:50px;height:50px;"/></td><td>DAS Direct Attached Storage</td><td>80.00</td><td>100.00</td><td>Thunderbolt</td><td>8</td><td>900</td><td>5/8/8</td><td>600</td><td>fsdfd</td><td style='display:none;'>1</td><td><a href=http://fsdfds target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='38' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr><tr> <td>Promise</td><td>Zdjęcie</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/depositphotos_12071772-Website-Development-PHP-HTML-Arrows.jpg" style = "width:50px;height:50px;"/></td><td>DAS Direct Attached Storage</td><td>4564.00</td><td>999999.99</td><td>Thunderbolt</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>1</td><td>300</td><td>SPrawdzam czy działaja fotki .... .... .. .. .. .</td><td style='display:none;'>1</td><td><a href=http://feasd target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='39' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr><tr> <td>Promise</td><td>g</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/rc.jpg" style = "width:50px;height:50px;"/></td><td>DAS Direct Attached Storage</td><td>45.00</td><td>5.00</td><td>Thunderbolt</td><td>12</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>l</td><td>l</td><td style='display:none;'>1</td><td><a href=http://l target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='40' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr><tr> <td>Promise</td><td>jj</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/" style = "width:50px;height:50px;"/></td><td>DAS Direct Attached Storage</td><td>1.00</td><td>1.00</td><td>Thunderbolt</td><td>2</td><td>j</td><td>j</td><td>j</td><td>n</td><td style='display:none;'>1</td><td><a href=http://j target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='43' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr><tr> <td>Promise</td><td>jj</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/" style = "width:50px;height:50px;"/></td><td>DAS Direct Attached Storage</td><td>1.00</td><td>1.00</td><td>Thunderbolt</td><td>2</td><td>j</td><td>j</td><td>j</td><td>n</td><td style='display:none;'>1</td><td><a href=http://j target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='44' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr>            </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: So, @patwoj98, what is your question? What do you want to filter & how?

Comment: First, I want to know: It is possible to filter table TD with jQuery by input ="range" value? If yes, how?

Comment: @patwoj98 What is expected result ? What is the filter ?

Comment: This is my full code: https://jsfiddle.net/f3x5jfjg/14/
When I click checboxes it show me only values like a checkboxes alt. Now I want to do the same but with range.

Comment: @patwoj98 Is requirement to log `input type="range"` values on `click` of `'input.szukajnapraw'` ?, or at separate block of `js` ?

Comment: It is separate block. It is only requirement. I don't know how do it, because I work with PHP, not jQuery , but client wanted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that can be done. You would have to take advantage of the `change` event, not the `click` event though.

As the ranges are wide, and it's hard to find a match I have set a match by default and used `addClass()` and `removeClass()` instead of `hide()` and `show()` just to demonstrate how to approach this. Pick any other match, if you can find one, and set your ranges to it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ranges = $('div.box > input[type=range]'),
        table  = $('table.table'),
        hrow   = $('tr:has(th)', table),
        orow   = $('tr:has(td)', table);

    ranges.on('change', function() {
        //init range object
        var orange = [];

        //determine value setting & index for each range
        ranges.each(function() {
            var thisrange = {};
            thisrange.value = this.value;
            thisrange.label = $(this).prev('label').text().trim();
            thisrange.column  = $.inArray( thisrange.label, $('th',hrow).map(function(i,v) {
                return $(v).text().trim();
            }) );
            $(this).next('label').text( this.value );
            orange.push( thisrange );
        });

        //hide [remove hightlight] all rows but header
        orow.removeClass('highlight');

        //show [hightlight] rows with values
        orow.filter(function() {
            var result = true,that = this;
            $.each( orange, function(i,v) {
                result = result && $('td',that).eq(v.column).text().trim() == v.value;
            });
            return result;
        }).addClass('highlight');
    }).change();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/ajwj7kt9/7/)

**NOTE**: Some values in the filter columns are non-numeric and would never be set on the range! And some numeric values are out of range.

**Update**

Here is a version that will filter just by the changed range. When the page loads it filters by the value of the first range.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ranges = $('div.box > input[type=range]'),
        table  = $('table.table'),
        hrow   = $('tr:has(th)', table),
        orow   = $('tr:has(td)', table);

    ranges.on('change', function() {
        var value = this.value,
            label = $(this).prev('label').text().trim(),
            column  = $.inArray( label, $('th',hrow).map(function(i,v) {
                return $(v).text().trim();
            }) );

        //display the new value
        $(this).next('label').text( value );

        //hide [remove hightlight] all rows but header
        orow.removeClass('highlight');

        //show [hightlight] rows with values
        orow.filter(function() {
            return $('td',this).eq(column).text().trim() == value;
        }).addClass('highlight');
    }).eq(0).change();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/ajwj7kt9/9/)

Comment: Nice this is it. But it isn't working. http://jsfiddle.net/ajwj7kt9/6/
Range 1 is working with 8 column, r 2 with 9, r 3 with 11. Can you do it?

Comment: Not sure whether you know what you want :) It was working but you changed the indexes and now it is not working. The indexes are picked up dynamically. In fact I have upgraded to a more dynamic version -- see update. Try to follow what's going on before you change; it's very straight-forward. Let me know if I should add more comments :)

Comment: My English is low so it's hard to me to say what I mean :) 
When "Ilość dysków" range is 5, it should show only table rows where td "ilość dysków" is equal to 5. Do you know what I mean? It doesn't work at your code :(

Comment: Do you want all the ranges to applied simultaneously? Or do you want to apply only one range at a time?

Comment: One at the moment. When the user change the value 1, it sorted rows by this one.

Comment: Did you say sort? And what row should it filter by when the page loads?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77336/discussion-between-patwoj98-and-peterka).

Comment: So, no sort. I made mistake :) I thought "filter". It should get only rows where td number 8 (in case range 1) is equal to value of range 1. Come to chat, if you can :)

Comment: Sorry I can't join chat right away but check update.

Comment: Nice, you are awesome :)

Comment: this highlights doesn't work with all of options. Some work, some no. Look: ilość dysków with val 6 work, but with val 4, doesn't work. Why? It also don't highlighting all of the results where value is equal to range.

Comment: You almost lost me there. Can you create a demo that clearly shows the issues you listed. I do not see any of those issues on my demo. :(

Comment: Please check this site: http://bloober.vot.pl/macierze/ 
I use it here. Could you check code and find error?

Comment: If you take your time and use dev tools you'd see that the class `highlight` is being added correctly -- even when the page loads. However, the rule for the `highlight` class conflicts with the rule `.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}`. Just so to confirm, locate the rule and comment it out. A better solution would, of course, be to make the rule for `highlight` more specific than the above rule. :)

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But at this site, front developer use a bootstrap so I can't modify rules. How can I change it  ?

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `.each()` , where `i` is index of element within collection , `el` is element , `el.value` is value of `input type="range"` current  element within loop

```
$("input[type=range]").each(function(i, el) {
  console.log(el.value);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f3x5jfjg/15/

Comment: Can you added to jsfiddle function onchange to search? For example: range value = "10", td number 8 is searching and where is the same value, show it.